# Jquery on.('click') function not working in Firefox but works on Chrome

Tags: jquery, firefox, button, submit

I have this function to submit some data to my database by clicking on a button:

```
$(document).on('click','#buttonfeitbran',function(e){
        var elem = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "feitbran.php",
            data: "id="+elem.attr('iduser'),
            dataType:"json",  
            success: function() {
                location.reload();
            }
        });
                location.reload();
});
```

This code works well on Chrome but I can't get it right on Firefox, and I'm afraid on IE too, however I didn't tried on it yet.
If you could help me I'd aprreciate a lot! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is that second `location.reload();` doing there outside of the success handler. I think it is misplaced?

Comment: as @GolezTrol said, the second `location.reload();`will cause the browser to stop any AJAX call and immediately reload the page.

Comment: That location reload will just reload even before you could get an an answer to your ajax call.

Your problem is probably with you ajax and not with click event. Put a `console.log` or `alert` at top of your click event handler and see if it fires.

Comment: That was part of the problem, thank you! Ibut now the data is submitted but the page doesn't reload.

Comment: Maybe the result of the request isn't right. Please check the developer tools in the browser (network tab) to see if you get a 200 status code, the proper content and the proper content type headers.

Comment: I get a 200 OK status code.. I'm not really familiar with this kind of debugging so I don't really know what that means, sorry :S

Comment: I could get it to work! Thank you guys for your help! I needed to remove the dateType: "json".. I don't even know why I had it anyway :P